# Python xlrd read cell value syntax error

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn *xlrd*. When I tried to print the  value of the Cell in a sheet am getting error.

This is my code

```
    workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet.cell_value(0,0)

 'Test Case ID'

    sheet.nrows

15

    sheet.ncols

2

    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        print sheet.cell_value(0,col

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me with this error

Comment: Obviously missing a `)`

Comment: Is this supposed to be Python code? What is code, what is output?